# Not able to show all the data from database to the angular project

Tags: .net, angular, http, crud

I'm developing one project and in that i've used Angular for frontend, Asp.net for API and SQL-SERVER For Database. I'm wanted to show all the data from backend to the front api but not able to do show. I'v mentioned the code below, kindly help me.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>City</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let addr of service.AddressDetailsList">
            <td>{{addr.AddressID}}</td>
            <td>{{addr.Country}}</td>
            <td>{{addr.State}}</td>
            <td>{{addr.City}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormDetailsService } from 'src/app/Services/form-details.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-coming',
  templateUrl: './home-coming.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-coming.component.css']
})
export class HomeComingComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public service:FormDetailsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.getAddressDetailsnew().subscribe(data=>{
      this.service.AddressDetailsList=data;
    })
    
  }

}
```

```
readonly baseurl="http://localhost:5157/api/RegistrationFormDetails/";
  getAllState():Observable<RegistrationFormDetails[]>{
    return this.http.get<RegistrationFormDetails[]>(this.baseurl);
  }

  AddressDetailsList:AddressDetails[]=[];
 
  getAddressDetailsnew():Observable<AddressDetails[]>{
    return this.http.get<AddressDetails[]>(this.baseurl+"Address")
  }
```

```
 [HttpGet("Address")]

        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Address>>> GetAddressDetails()
        {
            return  await _context.Addresses.ToListAsync();
          
        }
```

I've attached the code above. I've mentioned all the details there, while runing that code i'm not able to see the data only the header i'm able to see in the brower.

Comment: My issue is still not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialise a variable locally in your component and use that to fill the template, not involving the service.

Your component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-coming',
  templateUrl: './home-coming.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-coming.component.css']
})
export class HomeComingComponent implements OnInit {

  listData: AddressDetails[];  

  constructor(public service:FormDetailsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.getAddressDetailsnew().subscribe((data: AddressDetails[]) => {
      this.listData = data;
    })
  }
}
```

The template

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let addr of listData">
        <td>{{addr.AddressID}}</td>
        <td>{{addr.Country}}</td>
        <td>{{addr.State}}</td>
        <td>{{addr.City}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I tried the same thing but it is still not showing. while printing the listData in console, it is showing as undefined. Now I've updated the API method for reference, kindly have a look.

Comment: It seems then the issue is in fetching the data from the DB. Did you try putting a breakpoint in the API and follow the flow from there? To proof the FE/BE part is fine, you can return an hardcoded array from the API. If that part is fine, then you can debug why you cannot fetch the data from DB

Comment: When i fetch the data from api and then call that method in ngoninit and print it then the value is showing in the console. Still not able to resolve this

Comment: Can you copy in the question the data you get in the ngOnInit? Is it an array? Since you use a ngFor it should be an iterable structure. Plus be sure that the properties you receive from the API match the ones in the client, even with the case.

Answer (score 0):

Everything was good in this, the problem lies in the naming convention, where Angular 14 is taking naming convention like this "userName" if the written value is "UserName" is this also. So changing the naming convention worked for me.

Above solution provided by **Francesco** was totally correct and after making change by following his code, I was able to get the solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).